# How to Hook-up an LED-Lit Rocker Switch with 115V AC Power W/o Blowing the LED?

Tags: led

This is the LED-Lit switch I have:
[image: My LED-Lit Switch]

The switch itself is rated for 10A125VAC/6A250VAC but there is also a "12V" label on the switch suggesting that the LED should be given 12V.

Now, if I were to connect my switch with AC source to power my power supply in the following configuration:

[image: Wiring Diagram]
, then my led will burn/blow.

How can I hook up my switch to on/off my power supply and have the led lit when powered on?

Answer (score 1):

it can be done . you would need to connect neutral direct to the load. the LED terminal would need to be connected to neutral via a series capacitor resistor network. You can find what components you need from searching the web for "lighting an LED from 115volts". Note that a special quality capacitor intended for line/mains use would be required. Like you suggested,it may be simpler and probably cost no more to buy a neon switch .

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore the lamp connection.  The neutral wire will connect directly to the load.

Of course, with this connection, the lamp will not be used, and will not light when the load is on.

Comment: I want my switch to on/off my power supply and have the led lit when powered on.

Comment: The switch you've shown is one which uses a neon lamp as an indicator. Do you have a diagram showing the switch you're talking about?

Comment: After more asking around, despite the 10A125VAC/6A250VAC markings, my switch is a repurposed AC switch designed for 12V DC circuits.  I'll just buy a rocker switch with neon lamp as it can handle 120V AC between Tin and Neutral.

Comment: @PhoenixOpenProject: YAY!